# How to change ABPeoplePickerNavigationController backButton color?

Tags: ios, abpersonviewcontroller

I use `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to get all contacts. I change the tintColor with `[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`, but when it push, the backItem `<Contacts` is still blue.

I tried this

```
`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`  
_picker.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and   before push

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPersonViewController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`,

it didn't work.
How to change it?

Comment: Appdelegate.m applicationDidFinishLaunch method set  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I have a custom MyTabController which has change the color with this method, I just want to change the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ` and its subControllers.

Answer (score 0):

try with following `code`..

```
- (IBAction)btnopencontact {

    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *objPeoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    [objPeoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:objPeoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: please try with updated `code`, i checked in ios7 and ios8 .

Comment: Yeah, it works. But how can I change the tintColor of BarItem?